# Can I run spring boot 1.4.x jar on java 11+?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I searched spring documentation and the release notes. The details provided are more towards development with a specific version. But these documentation fails to mention if the old jars can be run against new java versions.

Does anyone have any idea if spring boot `1.4.x` application compiled and built on `java 8` would run on `java 11+`.?

Comment: Probably not. Java 9 introduced breaking changes. You can try it. But I guess you did. And it didn't work.

Comment: Supposedly 1.5.x can be modularized (source: https://dzone.com/articles/migrating-springboot-applications-to-latest-java-v). Not sure if the same process will work for 1.4. I would run a jdeps command on your jars to get a list of dependencies and try to see if those are compatible with Java 11 to start

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

Spring Boot [1.4 is using Spring Framework 4.3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#new-and-noteworthy)
which does not support Java (JRE) 11

[image]

https://endoflife.date/spring-framework